# Bestway to Select Theme for All Device in Android

Tags: android, android-theme, device

Right now i am using all theme provided by Android. like

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
```

And

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

But My question is **What is best practice to apply theme?** Which can **Efficiently** run in all device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can Efficiently run in all device.

what do you mean by all devices ? 
each device has an API OS
you can't use android:Theme.Holo.Light for an Older APIs less than API 14 which is android 4.0

if you want to apply a Theme that will work in all APIs( old and new version of android)
you will need to use a support library

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

> To have this theme use the newer holographic theme when the
>   application is running on Android 3.0 (API Level 11) or higher, you
>   can place an alternative declaration for the theme in an XML file in
>   res/values-v11, but make the parent theme the holographic theme:

Comment: Which is minSdkVersion for support Library .!

Comment: Android 1.6 (API level 4) and up. Check the link that I provide in the Answer !

Comment: @MehulPatel Theme.holo.Light.DarkActionBar is only a valid theme for api level 14 (Android 4.0) and above.

Comment: @b3du But i have to set minSdkVersion=11 because i have used so many extra library that support over 11. So now what can i do.! and I want to set holo.Light theme for all Device.

Comment: you can't use holo for all Sdk less than 14 ,, you will need to use     <stylename="AppBaseTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: if you used extra libraries that support over 11 .. you will need to change them too .. there is always a way.

Comment: i know that @b3du so what is the way to solve that ?

Comment: you have to change them .. If you have a kind of library that support over than 11 sdk .. just hit that name of the library in google and write SUPPORT library for android .. eitherway you will need to rebuild your application or just stay as the same SDK you are about to targetting

Comment: I can't Set below 11 because many of library can't set below 11. And i need that holo.light theme.! thas why i am asking question here..!

Comment: sorry man but there will be no way to do it if you can't set them all below 11 .. thumbs up my answer please if you found it helpful.